# how to pass data to the view from function that called inside controller

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, argument-passing

I have controller that calls other function, but when I passed it to the view the data in the function did not passed-along.

controller `home.php`:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data[1] = 'Data1';
        $data[2] = 'Data2';
        $data[3] = 'Data3';

        $this->more_data(); // this calls other function

        $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
    }

    function more_data()
    {
        $data[4] = 'Data4';
        $data[5] = 'Data5';
        $data[6] = 'Data6';
    }
}
```

When I executed `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` in `vhome.php` view
It just showed data1, data2, and data3

```
array (size=15)
  '_ci_data' => 
    array (size=3)
      '_ci_view' => string 'vhome' (length=5)
      '_ci_vars' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'Data1' (length=5)
          2 => string 'Data2' (length=5)
          3 => string 'Data3' (length=5)
```

How to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `$data` is within a local scope and `get_defined_vars` only works on the scope it was called in which would be `index()`.

At the minute `$data` 4-6 is only available within the scope of the `more_data()` function and 1-4 is only available through the scope of the `index()` function.

Comment: how to make this `more_data()` variables available globally?

Comment: You cant make them available gloablly, that is the point of object oriented programming (OOP). You could assign them to a class property `$this->data`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Create a class attribute **`$data`**.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->data[1] = 'Data1';
        $this->data[2] = 'Data2';
        $this->data[3] = 'Data3';

        $this->more_data(); // this calls other function

        $this->load->view('vhome', $this->data);
    }

    function more_data()
    {
        $this->data[4] = 'Data4';
        $this->data[5] = 'Data5';
        $this->data[6] = 'Data6';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ah yes, this worked. actually i understood what @CarlMarkham said, but i only use `$this->data` in `more_data()` instead of use it both in `more_data()` and `index()`. my bad :)

Comment: Hope my answer helped :)

Comment: How was this accepted as the answer when it is exactly what I said, only I chose to give an explanation rather than give the code. All this answer does is give code and offer no explanation as to why this code is needed.

Comment: I think I explained him well with the code as he said. Also, I didn't see your comment when I first view the question.

Comment: hhahaa i wish i can accept 2 answers. my deepest thanks to both of you.

Comment: If you can, accept his answer and give me a vote up, that's fair.

Comment: Thanks for both , I gave one for you :)